# A application that can serve a PHP/MySQL a program over a network with low configuration

Tags: windows-7, php, mysql, web-server

I thought to look for free hosting + free domain names, but I'm not seeing any that fit my needs. So, an alternative approach.

I have an application prototype I'm building, I need to serve at will from a local machine to my corporate network for very short periods of time. Like a containerized Apache. Google doesn't help me much(maybe I can't think what to call it).

The key for me, is low configuration, so I don't have to get the teams network/server admin involved.

**Requirements**

- I am on Windows
- Supports PHP/MySQL/SQLite
- I don't want any changes to networking or firewall when not running
- No configuration files
- As simple as possible
- Free as in gratis/Free Trial

**Note**

- This may not exist, if anyone beleives it doesn't, by all means say so.
- If anyone knows if this kind of software has a name that will help search for it, please say so.

Comment: A web server that has no configuration files? This is a little unrealistic.  And without opening a firewall? Try https://winginx.com/  or XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

I tired to post to your old question, but you deleted it. Plenty of Google answers for what you asked (free hosting php mysql shell), e.g. http://www.one.com/en/ftp-php-mysql-ssh-sftp

If you want to develop locally, the easiest way is to use [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html).

Comment: One.com looks good, but doesn't provide a domain name. I need the whole kit and kaboodle for a short period since I am not likely to get a server stood up for this. Also, Xampp is good, but I really want a no frills way making this accessible on my local network. Sorry if I'm not clear.

Comment: http://www.one.com/en/  has a list of 8 bullet points. #6 is domain ... I guess I missed something? Maybe you have to pay for the domain & it's only hosting that's free (hmmm, someone has to pay for domain registration - unless your domain is localhost ;-)? Is it truly necessary to have a domain for development? Can't you just switch URLs when you go live? And XAMPP is as no-frills as I know (much easier than installing Apache)

Comment: I think you have to pay for the domain. That's what I got out of it. I'll double check. I was hoping that someone would provide a temp subdomain for free. And Xampp is no frills, the only thing easier is Vagrant or the PHP Server with SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can get permission from your network folk to have 2 MAC addresses on one network jack...

1. install VirtualBox
2. Start new VM, install whatever flavor of Linux you like
3. Set VMs network card to be on the "Bridged" network, bridged to your real network card in your host machine
4. Configure Linux server as a LAMP box
5. Set up your app files, databases, etc
6. Turn on VM when you need to serve yourself (development) or others on your LAN.

The good news is that you can probably find a pre-configured virtual appliance that will do just about all of that, except perhaps the "put network card onto Bridged network" which is just a click or two in the GUI ....